# TortoiseSVN - How to revert files marked for delete?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was reorganizing some projects by copying (not moving) some folders under version control to a new structure. After that all my original files are marked for delete!

I can't find any alternative to unmark them for delete. Added files have the option to "Revert Add", but nothing for deleted.

I have tried "update" and "clean-up" but they refuse...
// thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one way that i know, is to select the ones that are marked as deleted, and just mark them as added, then commit. they will then be marked as "replaced" in the commit menu. once you commit nothing really happens to the files, they are just green again like normal.

Comment: +1v Your solution will keep the changes so I think this is the "safe" one to use :)

Answer (score 4):

Right-click your checkout folder, or the directory you accidentally deleted the files from. From there, you should be able to select TortoiseSVN > Revert, and see all of your missing files.

Alternatively, you can open the Commit dialog and see your changes there: from there, you can also revert them (select, right-click) and then close the dialog without actually committing anything.

Comment: +1 I tried your solution because it was easy :) But the easy way is usually the lazy way. It did revert... to my previous version so I lost all my changes. But I had of course made a backup first :)

Comment: Good solution. Instead of making check out you can just create file/folder with the same name as deleted one and revert it.